# TinyMCE Editor unable to select when table td contains span tag in IE11 only . Not working in all Tinymce versions

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, tinymce, tinymce-4, tinymce-plugins

http://fiddle.tinymce.com/u0gaab/1

it think the issue has something to do with `valid_elements`. When I remove this the `span` tag is removed. This is working fine in Chrome. I cannot change the valid elements since I cannot modify the HTML code. Can we handle this with any scripts or some polyfill for IE11?

Comment: only in ie please some of the blank cells are not selectable

Comment: http://fiddle.tinymce.com/u0gaab/1

Comment: see some of the blank cells are not selecting in IE11 ( valid_elements are '*[*]' )

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution on my own

Here is the solution :

> add to tinymce init : init_instance_callback : "checkIEBlankIssue"
>
> ```
> function checkIEBlankIssue(e) { 
>       if(tinyMCE.isIE) {
>           e.on('click', function (e) {
>               if(e.target.innerText === ""){ // fields not selecting if the content inside is blank
>                   tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.setNode(e.target);
>               }
>           });
>       }
>   }
> ```

select the node manually in ie